# Is it possible to use template arguments like C++ in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use C++ like template class in dart to generalize the API_provider layer.
But the following code does not run for an T.myName is undefined method.
Is there a way to use member function of T?

e.g.

```
abstract class AC<T> {
  void sayHello() {
    print(T.myName); # undefined method
  }
}

class Info {
  static const name = "hoge";
  String myName() => name;
}
```

I want to achieve like the following code.

```
abstract class BaseProvider <T> {
  static const String baseUrl = 'localhost/';
  Future<List<T>> parseList (String Url){
    // parse Json to List
    // and T.fromMap() is necessary here
  }
}

class MyModelProvider extends BaseProvider<MyModel> {
  Future<List<MyModel>> searchByName(String name) => parseList(baseUrl + 'my_model?query=${name}');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast `T` to a class which has a `myName` method. This code will work :

```dart
abstract class AC<T> {
  void sayHello() {
    print((T as Info).myName);
  }
}
```

However I would suggest to write an abstract class like `ClassWithMyNameMethod`, which will be implemented by all your model classes :

```dart
abstract class ClassWithMyNameMethod {
  String name;
  String get myName;
}

class Info implements ClassWithMyNameMethod {
  @override
  String get myName => name;

  @override
  String name = 'hoge';
}

abstract class AC<T> {
  void sayHello() {
    assert(T is ClassWithMyNameMethod);
    print((T as ClassWithMyNameMethod).myName);
  }
}
```

Comment: But this kind of defeats the purpose of having a generic parameter.

You could force `T` to be a subclass of `Info` by using `AC<T extends Info>...`.

Comment: Updated answer with a more generic approach.

Comment: That seems the best solution to prepare Abstract Class with ClassWithMyNameMethod.
I got my understanding deeper. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, I could not define named constructor in the Abstract class.
I avoid this by defining a member, dynamic Function(Map<String, dynamic> map) and overrode this function in the extended classes.